# Permissions required to modify SELinux labels

Tags: permissions, selinux

I am writing code that is SELinux aware. I am new to this security module and am having a steep learning curve.

For my code to work in an SELinux environment, I need to be able to relabel files. For example I am mounting temporary filesystems, and want to restore the original label after doing the mount.

Obviously I need to be root (have CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability) for the mounting part, but do I need to be root for the relabeling part?

On Fedora I am allowed to relabel files owned by myself, for example I can do the following as unprivileged user:

```
$ touch /tmp/test
$ ls -Z /tmp/test
unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0 /tmp/test
$ chcon system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0 /tmp/test
$ ls -Z /tmp/test
system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0 /tmp/test
```

It appears there is no permission to relabel files owned by a different user.

But now I found the following in the RedHat [manual](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-security-enhanced_linux-working_with_selinux-selinux_contexts_labeling_files#sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files-Temporary_Changes_chcon):

> SELinux policy controls whether users are able to modify the SELinux context for any given file.

which seems to indicate that this behavior is indeed configurable, and that I cannot rely on being able to relabel files owned by myself.

**EDIT:**
It seems that Fedora implements this using `constraints`.

```
# dnf install setools-console
# seinfo --constrain
...
constrain file {relabelto create relabelfrom } (u1 == u2 or ( t1 == can_change_object_identity ));
...
```